# Exclude a folder from dbt docs generate

Tags: dbt

I've been working on a project and I have installed some `dbt_packages`, namely `codegen` & `dbt_utils`.

When I create and view the dbt docs using `dbt docs generate` & `dbt docs serve`, I still [see those two packages as projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMCBP.png).
Tried the following so far:

1. [This](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/docs) which works fine for models already in my `model-paths` i.e. they don't show up in the docs site. The `dbt_packages` folder is not in my `model-paths` but at the same level as my `models` directory. When adding the `dbt_packages` folder in the `model-paths` line of my `dbt_project.yml`, I get multiple errors about the `version:` in multiple `.yml` files in the `dbt_packages` directory. The error has to do with the version number not being an integer.
2. Adding a `properties.yml` file in the `dbt_packages` folder with the syntax used in the previous point. Nothing still.
3. I also tried passing the `--exclude` argument using the syntax in the [dbt documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/node-selection/syntax), but it didn't work. They all return `The selection criterion 'tag:packages' does not match any nodes` (in this example for the `tags` syntax, but the output is the same for the rest of the syntaxes in the documentation link right above.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to here:
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/7259
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/6014

The selector currently only supports the compile phase, and does not support the selection of specific models when building catelog in dbt docs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).